# Where can I find technical drawings for computer parts?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, 3d-printing, drafting, computer

I want to 3d print a custom computer case, I have the skillset to do so, however, I do not know where to find the technical drawings required. I need drawings for a 280mm Radiator, an ITX Motherboard, and various other parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would research component manufactures web sites. It is highly unlikely that you will find all the information in on location. Here our example web site links to get started.

- [NZXT - Mini ITX Computer cases](https://sta3-nzxtcorporation.netdna-ssl.com/uploads/download/attachment/758/H210i_H210-manual-ver8-070720-web.pdf)
- [Fractal Era ITX Computer cases](https://www.fractal-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Era_Product-Sheet_EN.pdf)
- [Mini-ITX Mainboard Specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20110613223644/http://www.via.com.tw/en/downloads/whitepapers/initiatives/spearhead/ini_mini-itx.pdf)
- [Hydro Series™ H100i RGB PLATINUM 240mm Liquid CPU Cooler](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Liquid-Cooling/Dual-Radiator-Liquid-Coolers/Hydro-Series%E2%84%A2-RGB-Platinum/p/CW-9060039-WW#tab-tech-specs)

Another good place to look for is computer parts trade shows in your local area. With the current ongoing COVID-19 situation not sure if any of these trade fair active.

Comment: GrabCAD and Tracepart also have a nice library.